# Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'hash' could not be found

Tags: ember.js, ember-components, ember-addon

I tried to decompose my Ember.js application into different addons. I've moved some of my components to the addon. But at tests of components who use `hash` helper got the following error:

`Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'hash' could not be found`

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addon project had an ember version of 2.2. The hash helper was introduced in 2.3.

See the [changelog](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_hash-helper) of ember versions.